# how do I select rows from inside a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to extract 50 rows from a data frame

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

    states = 
    readHTMLTable(getURL("https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_area"), 
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    states[3:52]
```

but instead of getting the 50 rows that i need i just get this for the out put 50 times:

```
 $<NA>
 NULL
```

Comment: Look at the structure of this data: it's a list of data frames--in this case, a list of only 1 data frame, but a list nonetheless. `states[[1]]` extracts the data frame at the first index

Answer (score 0):

Your output is a `list` and you cannot subset elements using `[2:52]`. You need to convert list to `data.frame` before subsetting.

Try this -

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

states = readHTMLTable(getURL("https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_area"), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
as.data.frame(states)[3:52,]
```

Comment: Since this is a list as you point out, you're better off extracting the first (or whichever) element of the list, which is itself a dataframe